# What is the way to import application hosted on GAE, into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I have some applications running on `GAE`. I was using netbeans to maintain the applications but have now shifted to eclipse. I have installed the necessary plugins required to run and deploy GAE apps.

I want to import those applications hosted on `GAE` into `eclipse`. How can I do this in eclipse ?

Comment: If you have the source code, you can simply import the project: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm

Answer (score 1):

Create a new workspace in Eclipse and create new projects there with the same names and application ids as your existing applications.  Create the same Java namespaces as you had in NetBeans in these new projects.  Import the source code files from the NetBeans directories into the new Eclipse project namespaces.

This manual approach is the most likely to succeed.  Various shortcuts hoped for by lazy people have a greater risk of failing because of undocumented differences between NetBeans and Eclipse.